# Find the common value over partition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this :

```
Loan_Num asset LTV
1         20    0.2
2         20    0.2
3         20    0.12 
4         20    0.2
5         10    0.3
6         10    0.3
7         10    0.22 
8         10    0.3
```

And I want to add a common value to this table by the group of asset.

```
Loan_Num asset LTV   cV
1         20    0.2  0.2
2         20    0.2  0.2
3         20    0.12 0.2
4         20    0.2  0.2
5         10    0.3  0.3
6         10    0.3  0.3
7         10    0.22 0.3
8         10    0.3  0.3
```

Any suggestions how to do this? is there a built in function for common value?

Comment: I think he is asking for the TLV value that repeats the most for that partition by

Comment: @GiladGreen - That makes sense. So `@Jordan` in that case what happens if there are ties and two values are equally common?

Comment: the highest of both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this would be

```
WITH CTE1
     AS (SELECT *,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [asset], [LTV]) AS C
         FROM   YourTable),
     CTE2
     AS (SELECT *,
                RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [asset] ORDER BY C DESC, [LTV] DESC) AS R
         FROM   CTE1)
SELECT [Loan_Num],
       [asset],
       [LTV],
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN R = 1
               THEN [LTV]
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY [asset]) AS cV
FROM   CTE2
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PXFE58026)

Though actually this would be slightly more efficient as it removes a sort

```
WITH CTE1
     AS (SELECT *,
                COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [asset], [LTV]) AS C
         FROM   YourTable),
     CTE2
     AS (SELECT *,
                MAX(C) OVER (PARTITION BY [asset]) AS MaxC
         FROM   CTE1)
SELECT [Loan_Num],
       [asset],
       [LTV],
       MAX(CASE
             WHEN C = MaxC
               THEN [LTV]
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY [asset]) AS cV
FROM   CTE2
```